# passwordConfirm rules in vee-validate 4.0

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vee-validate

I'm using `vue3` and `vee-validate 4.0`

This is my code.

If the password is the same, return the true and If the passwords are not the same I want to return `password is not same`

But In the rules named `validatePasswordConfirm`, I want to compare the password I entered with the `passwordConfirm` I entered, but I think I'm referring to the wrong value.

How can I compare `password` and `passwordConfirm`?

```
          <div class="input-box">
            <span class="details">비밀번호</span>
            <Field
              :rules="validatePassword"
              type="password"
              placeholder="비밀번호를 입력하세요"
              v-model="info.password"
              name="password"
              required />
            <ErrorMessage name="password" />
          </div>
          <div class="input-box">
            <span class="details">비밀번호 확인</span>
            <Field
              :rules="validatePasswordConfirm"
              type="password"
              placeholder="비밀번호를 확인하세요"
              v-model="info.passwordConfirm"
              name="passwordConfirm"
              required />
            <ErrorMessage name="passwordConfirm" />
          </div>
```

```
    validatePassword(value) {
      if(!value) {
        return '필수 입력 사항입니다.'
      }
      if(!/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[~!@#$%^&*()+|=])[A-Za-z\d~!@#$%^&*()+|=]{8,15}$/i.test(value)) {
        return '영문 소문자, 숫자, 특수문자 최소 한 개를 포함한 8~15자의 비밀번호를 입력해주세요.'
      }
      return true
    },
    validatePasswordConfirm(value) {
      if(!value) {
        return '필수 입력 사항입니다.'
      }
      if( this.password != this.passwordConfirm ) {
        return '비밀번호가 일치하지 않습니다.'
      }
      return true
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your `v-model`s it seems the structure of your data function is this:

```
data() {
  return {
    info: {
      password: '',
      passwordConfirm: '',
    },
  };
},
```

So you have to refer to the properties of `info` object. Change your condition to this:

```
if( this.info.password != this.info.passwordConfirm ) {
```

Comment: If I use mapState, Do I have to use mapState?
I already tried this.$store.state.password != this.$store.state.passwordConfirm
but It doesn't work, Howerver this.info.password != this.info.passwordConfirm is working!

Comment: That's a question about VueX store. You'll need to ask a separate question and provide relevant VueX code in it. Glad its working :) Could you please upvote and accept my answer as correct?